# Add key-value in JSON when calling an API

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

I am calling an API to get a list of properties. I obtain the jsons in the 'listings' file (https://api.nestoria.es/show_example?name=search_listings_es&syntax=1).

I am using zip codes to find each property and I need to add to each property its zip code. At the end I transform the json to a csv. I don't know how to add to each property the zip code (so I would need a new key-value to each result from the API call)...

Thanks!!!!!!!!!

Here it is the code:

```
from requests import get
import json
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
import csv

def get_nestoria(type):
#call the api
    api = 'http://api.nestoria.es/api?action=search_listings'
    place = '&place_name=' + area_name
    listing_type = '&listing_type=' + type
    json_es = '&encoding=json&pretty=1&country=es'
    page = '&page='

    api_input = api + place + listing_type + json_es
    response = get(api_input)

# Check if the API has worked
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("API called successfully")
    elif response.status_code == 400:
        print("Wrong request for" + area_name + ". Chechk this area is searchable")
    elif response.status_code == 403:
        print("Forbidden API call. Maximum number of calls reached.")
else:
    print("Wrong code", response.status_code)

    content_as_string = response.content.decode()
    # Decode JSON
    content = json.loads(content_as_string)
    content_response = content['response']

    # Number of total web pages neded for the area
    web_pages = content_response['total_pages']
    print('Number of pages in that area: ', web_pages)

    print("Numer of total properties " + area_name, content_response['total_results'])

    #2nd call to the API
    homes = pd.DataFrame()
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0'}
    for i in range(1, web_pages+1):
        api_input = api + place + listing_type + json_es + page + str(i)
        response = get(api_input, headers=headers)
        content_as_string = response.content.decode()
        content = json.loads(content_as_string)
        content_response = content['response']

        listings = content_response['listings']

        listings = pd.DataFrame(listings)

        if i==1:
            homes = listings
        else:
            homes = homes.append(listings, sort=True)
        time.sleep(3)     

    if homes.empty:
        homes = homes
    else:
        homes = homes[['bathroom_number','bedroom_number','car_spaces','commission','construction_year','datasource_name', 'img_height','img_url','img_width', 'floor',
                   'keywords','latitude','lister_url','listing_type','location_accuracy','longitude','price','price_currency','price_formatted','price_high','price_low',
                   'property_type','room_number','size','size_type','size_unit','summary','thumb_height','thumb_url','thumb_width','title','updated_in_days','updated_in_days_formatted']]

    return homes

homes = pd.DataFrame()

codigos_postales = ['01008']


today=datetime.date.today() #to change the name of the file
for i in codigos_postales:
    area_name = i
    temp = get_nestoria('buy')

    if i == 0:
        homes =temp
    else:
        homes = homes.append(temp,sort=True)



print('Number of extracted properties ', len(homes))
print(homes.head())
homes.to_csv('D:\\a000Master Big Data\\Prácticas\\Web scrapping\\Nestoria\\GranadaVenta'+str(today)+'.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = response.json()
```

Here data is the parsed response you get from sending the request.

You can then update the listings like this:

```
for i in data['listings']:
    i['ZipCode'] = zipcode
```

zipcode being the one you want to assign i.e the one you sent in the request.

You can either convert the data object into dataframe and then call `pd.to_csv` or use python in-built `csv.writer`

If you don't have the ZipCode you can use the google maps API to get that

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=valencia&sensor=true_or_false&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You will have to Sign Up to get your API key and then you will get zip code from the JSON response.

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example on how to use it.

```
api = 'http://api.nestoria.es/api?action=search_listings'
place = '&place_name=' + area_name
listing_type = '&listing_type=' + type
json_es = '&encoding=json&pretty=1&country=es'
page = '&page='

api_input = api + place + listing_type + json_es
response = get(api_input)
update = response.json()['response']['listings']
for i in update:
    i['Zipcode'] = zipcode
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Where do you say I should write that code? I have tried in different places in the code and it doesn't work.